# JavaFX : Deep copy ScrollPane with all childrens to use in another window

Tags: java, javafx, reference, scrollpane

I have a main window where I dynamically load data from DB and create `Button`s inside a `GridPane` which goes inside a `ScrollPane`!

Now I want to use the same `ScrollPane` with all its children on my dialog popup window so I don't need to load again all the data and images and all that stuff for my buttons, but when I pass my `ScrollPane` as an argument to the seconds window method where I fill it's `ScrollPane` with my old `ScrollPane`, it works nice, BUT, the `ScrollPane` on my first window gets empty!

I think this happens because of using the same `ScrollPane`, is there any way to Deep Copy and use exact same `ScrollPane` with all its children but different in reference from my old one??

Here's a demo code just for explaining what I try to do!

I invoke the method askForDrink() from my Main FirstWindowController and pass the `ScrollPane` as an argument there!

SecondWindow Controller:

```
public class SecondWindow_screenController {

@FXML
private ScrollPane secondsWindowScrollPane;

void askForDrink(Product product, ScrollPane scrollPaneFromFirstWindow) {

    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        // Here I set the GridPane from my old ScrollPane to the new ScrollPane
        Platform.runLater(()-> secondsWindowScrollPane.setContent(scrollPaneFromFirstWindow.getContent()));
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

SCREENSHOTS FROM MY APP:

[First Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAfF5.png)

[Second Window Dialog Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VObWx.jpg)

[Second Window Dialog Closed, missing Drinks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di9xL.png)

When I click on the middle section buttons, a new dialog window pops up, in which window I want to have the same drinks from my first window! 
You can see how my drinks `ScrollPane` gets empty when the second dialog window opens, and then when I close the second window, my drinks `ScrollPane` is still empty!

I don't need any code implementation, I just need to know what is my problem, Is it really that I am using the same reference of `ScrollPane` ??

Comment: A node can appear at most _once_ anywhere in the scene graph, as [documented](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html). However, deep copying nodes is not the proper solution.  You should have a model that you can pass around. When you create the dialog initialize the view with the model already loaded in the main window (_Note: You can share the same `Image` with multiple `ImageView`s_). You can encapsulate the view in a custom class to prevent code duplication.

Comment: [controlsfx gridview](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html)